# How do I implement a standard MBean that getter method not showing in operations?

Tags: java, jmx

When I create a getter method in the MBean with annotation "@ManagedAttribute", this method will showup in Attribute folder of my mbean in JConsole.

But unfortunetely, this getter method will also appears in Operations folder.

May I know is there any wrong I setting in the MBean?  or there is some approach that I can prevent the getter method showing in operations?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34072935/250517