# Spring ManagedAttribute appears in the Operations tab of the JMX console

Tags: jmx, visualvm, jconsole, spring-jmx

My MBeans are annotated using Spring annotations as follows:

```
@ManagedAttribute(description = "returns the name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Now, whenever I open a JMX Console (be it VisualVM or JConsole), I can see the attributes of my beans in the Attributes tab, but I can also see the getName() method exposed in the Operations tab. Is there a way in which I can only see the attribute in the Attribute tab (i.e. hide it from the Operations tab)?

Answer (score 2):

[AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/v4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler.java#L364-L365) has this code since 2008:

```java
// Attributes need to have their methods exposed as
// operations to the JMX server as well.
```

If you see the descriptor part of the `javax.management.modelmbean.ModelMBeanOperationInfo`, you'll see that there are parameters `role=getter` and `visibility=4`, which should (it depends on application that displays attributes/operations) be hidden somehow.

See more details under https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4232.

Comment: Thanks for the info! What I find really weird is that when browsing some of the JVM Mbeans through VisualVM, I can see lots of mbeans which have their attributes exposed, but none of the getters/setters, which makes me think that there must be a way in which you can circumvent the above-mentioned code in the AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler and implement this. Also, even if you can define the visibility param of a method, how can you make VisualVm disregard (i.e. not show) an operation which, say, has a visibility rating of 4?